# Inserting HTML tag with ACF into shortcode

Tags: plugins, functions, images, advanced-custom-fields, html

Let me start off by saying that I usually make alot of research before asking publicly for help - due to likelyhood of information already being on the web - altho I've done several days of reseach etc I'm still in agony...

I'm using Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields plugin - I've been able to make it show the image on my front page using a simple HTML code

```
<img src="[acf field='image' post_id=''. $post_id .'']" />
```

Where I created a custom field called 'image' . 
**Now** I want to create a shortcode to display this link if possible?
I've gone through alot of possiblities such as;

- [Official Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#HTML) where I got no real useful information (that I had the knowledge to use)
- [using echo - return with simple html between ''](http://prntscr.com/i2ke7i) (it broke the page)

Tried this too;

```
<?php
function my_shortcode() {
    $output = '';
    $output.= '<img src="[acf field='image' post_id=''. $post_id .'']" />';
    return $output;
}
```

Didnt take... then I went for the last one I could find on the web;

```
    function my_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?> <HTML> <img src="[acf field='image' post_id=''. $post_id .'']" /> <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Which ended into something like this on my website - [outcome](http://prntscr.com/i2ki7b)

I'm really out of my depth here guys... I'd be really glad if anyone would be willing to help me out a little!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `do_shortcode()` to execute shortcodes in your string

Full code should be like that

```
<?php
function my_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '', // Default value.
    ), $atts );

    $output = '[acf field="image" post_id="' . $atts['post_id'] . '"]';
    $output = do_shortcode( $output );
    $output = '<img src="' . $output . '" />';
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('my_link', 'my_shortcode');
```

Usage:

```
[my_link post_id="xxx"]
```

where xxx is id of the requered post.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for a really fast answer!
Did you mean to change the $output in here http://prntscr.com/i2kmu7  ?
Thanks a lot again

Comment: Exactly. do_shortcode() executes shortcodes in your string.

Comment: I have extended the answer

Comment: And I hope you understand that $post_id must be send to my_shortcode function

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edits and for the effort - http://prntscr.com/i2kto6 leads to http://prntscr.com/i2ku0y (empty site) - should I look into something different rather than the code itself ? Maybe some settings I should modify to enable the function.php file?

Comment: I assumed you have working code, and gave short answer. Now I have mentioned a problems and fully reworked it. Please see modified answer.

Comment: Thank you so much mister! I really dont know how to repay you! You're my salvation! :)))) If there's anything I can do to repay the kindness just say it! Thank you alot!

Comment: You are welcome. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
function my_shortcode(){
return '<img src="[acf field='image' post_id=''. $post_id .'']" />';
}
add_shortcode('image','my_shortcode');
```

Comment: All looks good.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i2ks7y ends up into http://prntscr.com/i2ksk1

I'm not really sure - should I edit some other document to enable the function.php - if I comment the whole php code -  the site's working again

Comment: For the last time: Please stop posting plain code snippets; **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry fuxia - I'll learn from here and try better next time!